# Python3.6 Scapy receives ICMP responses even from dead hosts

Tags: python-3.x, virtualbox, centos7, ping, scapy

Got strange stuff. Setup: VirtualBox + CentOs7 + python3.6 + scapy2.4.0

Got network with only 4-5 hosts active: gateway, CentOs in VirtualBos, PC on which VirtualBox running and something else.

Trying to do:

```
ans, unans = sr(IP(dst='10.10.10.1-100')/ICMP(), iface = 'enp0s3', retry=0, timeout=1)
Begin emission: ...

Received 1822 packets, got 99 answers, remaining 1 packets

ans
Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:99 Other:0

unans
Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:1 Other:0
```

> ans[x] - are legit ICMP Reply packets.
>
> unans[0] - no ICMP reply from CentOs VM itself

So looks like everything is alive instead of 4-5 hosts which actually are alive

What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: You may just be longing yourself

Answer (score 0):

You want to know the possible reason, but scapy is not giving you enough details. So use tcpdump:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -e -c 200 icmp
```

Send the probe packets while tcpdump is running, in order to view address and timing details. It is possible you are seeing lots of perfectly normal ICMPs, for example port unreachable, or network unreachable. Tcpdump will tell you exactly what went over the network interface.